# after `Query execution was interrupted` can not access table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I was running a simple query in MySQL, joining two tables and getting where it doesn't match. Both tables have 500k data. my query was something like

```
select count(*) from t1 join t2 t1.id <> t2.id
```

and after 300 seconds I got following error

> Error Code: 1317. Query execution was interrupted

after that, I could  not run a simple query on that table, like

```
select * from t1 limit 50
```

but all other tables were working and my system also got down for a while. Finally, I restarted my MySQL server then everything started working.

Any idea why my table got stuck??

TIA

Comment: `t1.id <> t2.id` ?? Not equal??

Comment: I think that means you are joining each row in T1 with ALL BUT ONE row in T2. Making a HUGEMUNGOUS set of data

Comment: I was trying to get unmatched data from the table. I understand that because of my query execution was interrupted. But why my table got locked?

Comment: See the answer below

Comment: ok, I understand that my table got locked and I have to unlock the table, but I have encountered that error multiple times but the table never got locked.  May be expensive query caused that. Thanks for your co-operation.

Comment: Really depends upon what the query was doing when the crash occured as to whether is will crash a table or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table was locked, if a query crash for some reason, you have to kill your query to unlock you table (or restart your mysql server)

[image]